# Convert "Year-Quarter" to date format in R?

Tags: r, date, as.date

How can I convert the following vector in R to an as.Date format?

```
date= c( "2023-Q3" ,"2021-Q1", "2017-Q1", "2009-Q1", "2001-Q1", "1988-Q4")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `yq` function from lubridate. This will give you the first date of the first month of the quarter

```
lubridate::yq(date)
[1] "2023-07-01" "2021-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2009-01-01" "2001-01-01" "1988-10-01"
```